# Precondition Failed Error while trying to send Message to Teams-Chat | Graph API | C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

everytime I try to send a Teams-Message I recieve an error.
I couldn`t figure out how to fix it and hope someone here has a clue for me.

**Error Message:**

Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: "Code: PreconditionFailed
Message: Requested API is not supported in application-only context
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date: 2022-10-20T12:07:44
request-id: 88e01bd9-370c-4739-b0bd-0244892475e2
client-request-id: 88e01bd9-370c-4739-b0bd-0244892475e2
ClientRequestId: 88e01bd9-370c-4739-b0bd-0244892475e2
"

**Permissions:**

**Delegated Permissions:**
Chat.ReadBasic, Chat.Read, Chat.ReadWrite, Chat.Create, ChatMember.Read, ChatMember.ReadWrite, ChatMessage.Send, Chat.ReadWrite, Channel.Delete.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

**Application Permissions:**
ChatMember.Read.All, ChatMember.ReadWrite.All, Chat.ReadBasic.All, Chat.Read.All, Chat.Create, Chat.ReadWrite.All, Channel.Delete.Group, Channel.Delete.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

**Code I am using:**

```
         /* ------------------------------------------------------------- */
     /// <summary>
     /// 
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="userId"></param>
     /// <param name="chatID"></param>
     /// <param name="messageText"></param>
     /// <param name="scopes"></param>
     /// <returns></returns>
     public ChatMessage SendMessageToChat(string userId, string chatID, string messageText, string[] scopes = null)
     {
       return SendMessageToChatAsync(userId, chatID, messageText, scopes).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     }
    
     /* ------------------------------------------------------------- */
    
     private async Task<ChatMessage> SendMessageToChatAsync(string userId, string chatID, string messageText, string[] scopes = null)
     {
       GraphServiceClient graphClient = this.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(scopes);
    
       var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
       {
         Body = new ItemBody
         {
           Content = messageText
         }
       };
    
       return await graphClient.Users[userId].Chats[chatID].Messages
         .Request()
         .AddAsync(chatMessage);
    
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: what I post below is based on the assumption that you used client credential flow.  Pls kindly let me know your value for `scopes`, and if my assumption is wrong, pls kindly let me know.

Comment: If more people are interrested in this question, I also asked it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1059937/precondition-failed-error-while-trying-to-send-mes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you write is `await graphClient.Users[userId].Chats[chatID].Messages`, so it's obvious that you want to send chat message to a teams chat but not a teams channel.

Let's see the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) for this graph api. It does not support application permissions. Combining with your error message, I deduce you used client credential flow and set the scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. So you need to use delegate api permission. That means you need to have a module to let users sign in with their `user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com` account then calling graph api. If what you had is a web application, you need to integrate AAD like [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) demonstrating. If you owned a daemon app, then your requirement can't be realized.

[image]

Comment: Yes your assumption is right, I use the client credential flow. 
My scope values are null which is referring to .default

I think my scopes are wrong but into what should I change them?

Comment: I shared a sample in my post, and if you are composing a web application, pls integrate AAD in your app following the document. Then you can use the `_graphServiceClient` in the controller to call graph api.

Comment: @Th3TV could you pls let me know what kinds of application you are composing? Web api app? Console app? or MVC app?

Comment: you want to call send chat message graph api -> this api doesn't support application permission -> you can't use client credential flow and can only use flow like auth code flow -> you have to have a sign in module which providing a page to let user sign in so that you can get the authorization for calling this api -> if you only have a web api project/console app which means you can't provide a web page to let users sign in, then you can't realize your requirement via this graph api.

Comment: ok, then it's a pity that you can't use api to accomplish your goal...